# Timer Task only runs after server restart in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, timer, scheduled-tasks

I have written a timer task where the timer scheduler runs only after the server restart, this task has to run after every 5 minute everyday.

**Source code**

```
Timer t = new Timer(true);
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ExtractionAndPopulationJobScheduler(applicationContext.getBean(ExtractionAndCleaningJobTask.class)), new Date(), 300*1000);
```

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear and add your source code, Have a look here => [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Is not clear what you want to achieve, I suggest you do add the current output and expected Output

Comment: could you add class where that code is located?